# Uploading video from Amazon to Facebook through Resumable function gives error

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, amazon-cloudfront, facebook-php-sdk

I've the feature where companies can share videos on our site from Amazon to their Facebook Page. I had used

```
$response = $fb->post("/{$page_id}/videos", $fbData, $accessToken);
```

and its working But I want to use the Resumable video functionality because only then they can upload large videos of size more than 1GB.

```
        $fb = new Facebook(array(
        'app_id' => $facebook_settings['app_id'],
        'app_secret' => $facebook_settings['app_secret'],
        'default_graph_version' => $facebook_settings['default_graph_version'],
    ));
    try {

        $fbData = array(
            'title' => strip_tags($data['title']),
            'description' => strip_tags($data['description']),
            'asset_key' => $asset_key,
            //'source' => basename($data['url']),
        );


        //$response = $fb->post("/{$page_id}/videos", $fbData, $accessToken);
        $response = $fb->uploadVideo($page_id, $data['url'], $fbData, $accessToken, 5, null);
    }

    catch(FacebookResumableUploadException $e) {

        $this->markFacebookVideoUploaded($asset_key, true, null, $e->getMessage());
    }
```

When I use this `uploadVideo` function it gives me error [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://d(this is url to video on Amazon).

It gives error when `uploadVideo` calls the start function in Facebook.php file which tries to get the filesize and I think It can't.
Any suggestion or solutions or someone has experienced it before? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL wrappers. Refer to List of Supported Protocols/Wrappers for a listing of which wrappers support stat() family of functionality.

HTTP(S) wrapper doesn't support stat()

So go to Facebook library FileUpload/FacebookFile.php, and replace

```
public function getSize()
{
  return filesize($this->path);
}
```

to

```
public function getSize()
{
   $head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($this->path, TRUE));
   return $filesize = $head['content-length'];
}
```